# Do the fields (structure) of MySQL tables get unique ids?

Tags: php, mysql, structure

I'm not talking about unique keys or auto_increments, suppose I have this structure:

```
mysql> describe email_notifications;
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| email_id      | int(11) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| email_address | varchar(100)     | NO   |     |         |                |
| course_id     | int(11) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I'm building (for fun, practice, and hopefully some practical use) a tool in PHP that will analyze the structure of each table in a database and then compare it to a newer one (to assist in Dev -> Live updates), and then spit out some MySQL queries (Such as `ALTER TABLE...`) that I can run on the live database in order to bring it up to speed.

The question - does each field get a unique id of some sort?

If I change email_address from `varchar(100)` to `text` (for example) or the name `course_id` to `cr_id`, is there any way for me to tell that it's still technically the same dataset? I don't want to run a Delete and Add, but instead rename it give it a new type.

Or if there's a better way to do it without some sort of MySQL ID, that would be great :)

Thanks!

Comment: You can maybe calculate the hash of the data.  The same values should generate the same hashes.

Comment: There might be something you can do with [CHECKSUM TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/checksum-table.html). However I'm not sure if checksum would give the same result for a field that was converted from varchar(100) to text (I would suspect the checksum changes even if the data is *technically* the same).

Comment: @RocketHazmat - could you elaborate? I'm not exactly following.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `information_schema.columns`.  The following are both unique keys in this table (even if they are not so defined):

```
TABLE_CATALOG, TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME     
TABLE_CATALOG, TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, ORDINAL_POSITION
```

When you change the name or type of a column, I do not believe that `ORDINAL_POSITION` is affected.  So, the second version may be what you are looking for.

This may then lead to the question "what if I change the name of a table?"  The `information_schema` tables can't help there, unfortunately.

Comment: I will check that out, thanks! :) And GAH! I didn't even think of renaming tables :(